# How Should Custom Functions Be Called For Single Posts?

Tags: plugins, customization

I have been trying to find the answer to this. I want to use the best method performance wise, but also want to make this solution portable as possible.

I have created a plugin that adds multiple post types and custom meta fields for each of these post types. Reviews is an example of this. I have a large database that isn't a part of wordpress that contains lots of video game information. When writing a review I have a box to add the name of the game being reviewed.

I have written a function displayGameInfo($gameID) as part of my plugin. In single.php i have the following code.This will output some information for the game just after the end of the main text body of a post.

```
 $postid =  get_the_ID();                   
 $gameid = get_post_meta($postid,'nb_gameids_key', true);               

 if(function_exists("displayGameInfo")) echo displayGameInfo($gameid);
```

People seem to be discouraging this method though and I agree with them in a way as this requires me to place a lot of custom programming within the theme. I would like if this was more portable across themes.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to add data to a post's content without having to touch the template.